# Silverlight Video Player that plays .MP4 & .FLV

Tags: silverlight, encoding, flv, mp4, silverlight-5.0

I am currently using the [Silverlight 2 Video Player](http://www.codeplex.com/sl2videoplayer) to stream videos.  I have been very pleased with it but it only seems to stream .WMV files.  Does anyone know if there is a good Silverlight video player that will stream other types of video files, especially .MP4 & .FLV?  I would be happy to use Silverlight 3 if necessary.

EDIT: Because I like this player and have not found a great option, I am considering encoding files as I receive them so that they will always be streamed later as a .WMV.  Unless I determine a good player (I am considering flash at this point), I will have to go down this road.

EDIT 2: Now that Silverlight has evolved quite a bit, are there any new players using Silverlight 5 that do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Try this link: [Silverlight Video Player with Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/05/04/silverlight-video-player-source-code.aspx)

Comment: Where do I find more documentation?  It may not be worth researching if I cannot verfiy that it can play .MP4 files.

Answer (score 2):

Just found [this Silverlight Media Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/) which looks interesting and more robust than the Silverlight Video 2 Player I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 2 supports the following standards of video:
• Windows Media Video 7 (WMV1)
• Windows Media Video 8 (WMV2)
• Windows Media Video 9 (WMV3)
• Windows Media Video Advanced Profile, non-VC-1 (WMVA)
• Windows Media Video Advanced Profile, VC-1 (WMVC1)